# API Gateway- SerializationException: Start of structure or map found where not expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, get, amazon-dynamodb, api-gateway

I have a REST api and a GET method to a DynamoDB table with this mapping template using Dynamo Query:

```
{
    "TableName": "table",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "#id = :v1",
    "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
        "#id": {
            "S": "uuid"
        }
    },
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":v1": {
            "S": "$input.params('id')"
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to call the endpoint(using url.amazonaws.com/v1/getid?id=itemid), I get

```
{
    "__type": "com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException",
    "Message": "Start of structure or map found where not expected"
}
```

I have an IAM role that allows Query to Dynamo attached. I haven't gotten this error before with my other GET methods so I assume it is something with 'uuid' being a reserved word. I can't change that so am I doing something wrong with the mapping template?